# Installing Laravel 4.1 with Laravel Installer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, installation

I'm trying to install Laravel 4.1 using the Laravel installer but the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation) isn't very descriptive.

Can someone please give a step by step guide on how to do this? I'm completely new to Laravel and PHP frameworks as a whole.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine running WAMP 2.2.

Comment: install composer. run `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist` .... how much easy it can get?

Comment: I'm trying to go about this way because they say "_This method of installation is much faster than installing via Composer_"

Comment: what other method you are trying?

Comment: No other method. I was referring to what's mentioned in Laravels' documentation.

Comment: i copied the info from laravel docs.... that's the standard way. where are you facing the difficulty?

Comment: @itachi I believe OP's trying to use the `Larave.phar` installation

Comment: Okay I managed to install it via Composer. @DamienPirsy is correct. I was trying to use the Laravel.phar method. I guess I forgot to mention it explicitly in the question. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Laravel means simply downloading Laravel Application bootstrap, which has to be placed in your project directory. That application has a **composer.json** file, which will, after you run `composer install` command, download all necessary dependencies (including core framework).

That is one way. Another preferred way is directly through:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name
```

In both cases, you need to have composer installed on your machine. Composer is a modern PHP package manager, which has a ton of benefits (autoloading, custom commands...).

There is really no need for two downvotes, especially when this guy was reading documentation, which he couldn't understand. We were all installing Laravel for the first time.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I got it installed using Composer. :)

Comment: FYI the reason that the laravel.phar way says that it's faster than the `composer` method is that it keeps the 'Laravel Application bootstrap' (as carousel calls it) within the phar itself, so that when you call `create` on it, it simply copies it latest version of the Laravel app skeleton, but it then does (as far as I'm aware) still install the dependencies via composer, thus it's not going to be *much* faster. (That said, composer caches tagged versions, so once you do it for the first time, assuming there are no updated to the dependencies, you get the these from the cache too.)

Comment: However, to keep the Laravel bootstrap contained within the phar up to date you have to update the phar on occasion, so I guess it's probably not that much quicker (I'd certainly update the phar every time I wanted to create a new app, thus it's the same time as doing it the `composer` way, but with more steps!).

Answer (score 18):

This information/answer isn't quite up to date anymore.  The instructions here will install the latest version which is no longer 4.1.  For those still wanting to install Laravel 4.1 (despite 4.2+ being out), use the following command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name 4.1
```

You could replace the 4.1 with 4.0 or 4.2 depending on your situation.

Laravel 4.1 is handy if you aren't in control of your PHP version and you're stuck back on 5.3.7

Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4.

When upgrading a project to a newer version of Laravel, be sure to review the [release notes](http://laravel.com/docs/releases)

Answer (score 1):

If you want install laravel via Laravel Installer use this method:
First, open up command line. then enter:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Now go to:

> C:\Users\ {User Name} \AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor

Copy and paste vendor in your destination folder.
Now in your destination folder hold the shift key down and press right click and in opened navigation menu click on "open command window here" then enter command below:

```
laravel new your_project_destination
```

Ex:

```
laravel new laraveltest
```